# Sorting content based on first field and outputting second field into new file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redhat

I've got a file which is like this:

```
 3 EOE
 5 APPLE
 6 NOBODY
```

i need to parse this and output all with '3' in the first column into filename.3, '4' into filename.4, etc... from the unix prompt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work (I haven't tested it):

```
while read num rest; do
   echo "$num $rest" >> "filename.$num"
done < inputFile
```

`read` will read a line of text, then split it up on whitespace into "words", like when you run a command. It will assign the first "word" to the first variable name (`num` in this case - which will get the number), the second "word" to the second variable name (`rest`), and so on. If it runs out of variables, it will append the remainder of the line to the last variable (`rest`, here).

When `read` processes a line successfully it returns zero, which is "success" in shell scripting, so the `while` loop will keep going, reading subsequent lines. When `read` hits the end of the file, it will return 1, stopping the `while` loop.

Answer (score 4):

```
awk '{print $2 >> "filename."$1 }' filename
```

If you want the *entire* line:

```
awk '{print $0 >> "filename."$1 }' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

using bash for loops, cut and grep

```
for i in `cut -s -d ' ' -f 1 input.txt`; do
    grep ^$i input.txt > filename.$i
done;
```